# C- uncorrect method needs to be corrected

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I have a problem which may look like if I copied my homework, but it's not my homework. It was part of a Test at University and I want to solve it (as well as others) at home so that I am prepared for the next Test. 
My goal here is that I understand so that I can solve similar questions on my own. I am familiar with high-level languages but C is one of my weaknesses, this is why I have problems here.

### The Question

Given the following method:

```
int safe_read(int fd, char *buff, size_t len){
    do {
        errno = 0;
        pos += read(fd, buff + pos, len);
        if (-1 == len) {
            if (ENTER != errno) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    } while(ENTER == errno);
    return pos;
}
```

and the following call:

```
pos = safe_read(STDIN_FILENO, msg, 225);
```

Analyse the code and answer the following questions:

1) Does `safe-read` return the number of bytes read correctly in all cases?

2) If not, how can this be fixed?

Well. For now, I already understood the following:

1)
No it does not, as for the following reasons:

-the caller may set fd to something invalid. 
 -pos is not properly initialized.
 -The variable ENTER is also not initialized.
 -if(-1==len) does not make sense as len is a parameter set by the caller, thus will alsways be true or false at one call.

-it is also not safe as it is possible to go beyond the buffer's maximum size (by setting len to a value >= sizeof(buff))

-it does not return the number of characters read in all cases, as f.e. when I read len characters the first time, And the second time it fails. I will then return zero even though len characters have already been read.

2) Here is my fix. 
initialize variables

/*
For a better understanding, I write what I understood about what this method is supposed to do:

-reads characters into char* buff.
-returns the number of characters read as int
-fd is a file descriptor of the file to read
-len is the number of bytes to be read

*/

```
int safe_read(int fd, char *buff, size_t len){
    int ENTER=0;
    int pos=0;
    do {
        errno = 0;
        pos += read(fd, buff + pos, len);
        if (len < 0) {
            if (ENTER != errno) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    } while(ENTER == errno);
    return pos;
}
```

Did I understand you correctly? Is my fix correct?

Thank you!

Special thanks to Paul Ogilvie for the help before my edit!

Comment: short answer is 'no'. f.e. what if `fd` is invalid. 2. pos is neither defined nor initialiesd, if `read()` encounters an error, the return value is `-1`and so on.

Comment: ^^ lol, 'safe_read' and 'pos' not declared.  'Analyse the code and answer the following questions' - homework tell.  No effort, so DCV.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no-effort homework dump.

Comment: If you ask questions whether the code works in ALL cases, shouldn't that code at least compile correctly?

Comment: A much more important question for you to answer is whether it reads anything correctly in the first place.

Comment: Your fix is not correct as, if `len` is the bufer's size, you still put more than `len` characters in the buffer upon the second read! You don't need variable `ENTER`, you just can compare `erno` with zero. You still check if len is -1, while it clearly can't. Lastly, you don't return the number of characters read; that would be `pos`, not `0`. So you didn't understand correctly; go back to the lab.

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains many errors and other members wonder if this is homework. But I'll attempt to help you. First your code:

```
int safe_read(int fd, char *buff, size_t len)
{
  int pos= 0;
  do{
    errno=0;
    pos+=read(fd, buff+pos, len);
    if(-1==len){
      if(ENTER!=errno){
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }while(ENTER==errno);
  return pos;
}
```

Variable `pos` was not defined and even it it was defined global, you probably would have to initialize it to zero.

Then your funny variable `ENTER`, which is neither defined and, more importantly, is never set in your code. So it won't change value. What is your intention with this variable?

Then `if(-1==len)`. `len` is a parameter that doesn't change so either it was -1 or it never will be. Clearly you want to check for an error on read, but this is not the way.

Then whether this is safe: no, it isn't. Assuming that `len` is the size of `buff`, then you repeatedly append `len` characters to `buff`, so at the second read it will go beyond the buffer's size.

And lastly whether this function will always return the correct number of characters read: no it doesn't. Suppose you read `len` characters the first time, and the second time it fails. You then return `0` but `len` characters had already been read.

Comment: You helped me a lot!
Thank you very much!